# VBA Evaluate with excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

how can I use VBA to Evaluate my string and apply a RoundUp in order to obtain "6" as a result

```
Sub EvaluateExample()
    Dim r As String
    r = "ROUNDUP(11/2)"
    Debug.Print Evaluate(r)
    'should print "6"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an argument in your `ROUNDUP()` call (number of digits after the decimal). Here's the correct way to do it:

```
r = "ROUNDUP(11/2,0)"
```

Comment: Right... daa tks for that